# how to change background color to imageView in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have a ImageView with a transparent image (PNG) therefore the image doesn't fill the complete rectangle of the image view, when mouse hover over the image view I want to change the background color of only the rectangle of the image view. In Css how I do it? do the image view node have the property -fx-background color? I tried and it's doesn't work for me.
I have a css file linked to the .FXML

Comment: Put the image view in a `StackPane` and use `-fx-background-color` on the `StackPane`.

Comment: `-fx-background-color`,is a property of `Region.`.  So, `image view` doesn't have this property.

Comment: thanks! that worked very well

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Bounds bound = ImageView.getBoundsInLocal(); //getting co-ordinates
ImageView.setEffect(ColorInput(bound.getMinX(), bound.getMinY(),
            bound.getWidth(), bound.getHeight(), Color.YELLOW));
```

By function should work.

Comment: this just painted the color OVER my ImageView and now I can't see the image.